# parse data in twisted dataReceived

Tags: json, node.js, kivy, twisted

I'm working on a Sonos controller Kivy app (running on RPi).  The sonos side of things is using node.js.  My kivy app currently sends a http request to get the state of sonos (volume, station, song, etc) then updates the labels and images.  This is working well, but I'd like to used twisted instead.  As a starting point, I'm running the sample Echo Server app found in the kivy docs (https://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html).  When I run it, dataReceived correctly gets the current status info on a Sonos state change.  This is awesome.  Unfortunately, the data is a mix of text and json.  I'm wondering if there is a way to parse the json that's returned.  Here's data

> content-type: application/json content-length: 1570 host:
>   localhost:8000 connection: close
>
> {   "type": "mute-change",   "data": {
>       "uuid": "RINCON_000000000000001400",
>       "previousMute": true,
>       "previousMute": false,
>       "roomName": "Office"   } }

Instead of using dataReceived, is there a better way?  I've been looking for a way just get the json (body) without all the header info, but havent found much that has worked.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Twisted Web](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html).  For example:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
import time

class EchoPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "I got: {}".format(
            request.content.read(),
        )

resource = EchoPage()
factory = Site(resource)
endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8880)
endpoint.listen(factory)
reactor.run()
```